# C# redirecting data to an already running console exe

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, process

What I want todo:

I want to start a built console application (AppB) from within another console application (AppA). AppA starts AppB without any arguments. All AppB does is to go into its `Main()` Method and call `Console.ReadLine()`.

Now I want that AppA sends a string of data over to AppB's `Console.ReadLine()`. Is this even possibel? (I know I can send streams to a new Console.exe but that's not what I need.)

Comment: Please [explain why you think you need this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). We did something like this years ago, and removed it because it caused too many problems with applications overwriting each others' screens and log files. You should consider storing the data in a database or message queue.

Comment: In short I just wanted to know how to pass arguments to an already running process without arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [RedirectStandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx):

```
     Process myProcess = new Process();

     myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "someconsoleapp.exe";
     myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     myProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

     myProcess.Start();

     StreamWriter stdInputWriter  = myProcess.StandardInput;
     StreamReader stdOutputReader  = myProcess.StandardOutput;

     stdInputWriter.WriteLine(password);

     var op = stdOutputReader.ReadLine();

     // close this - sending EOF to the console application - hopefully well written
     // to handle this properly.
     stdInputWriter.Close();


     // Wait for the process to finish.
     myProcess.WaitForExit();
     myProcess.Close();
```